# Using multiple tables for one asp net repeater datasource

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-table, repeater

I need to read data from multiple tables and display them in my aspx. So how should I solve this? I have tried to use two repeaters but that does not work either.

C#:

```
    var node = _administrationSystem.GetNodes(); //DataSet
    var operatorInfo = _administrationSystem.GetOperatorsInformation(userId); //DataSet

        var result = (from n in nodes.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                  join o in operators.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                  on n.Field<int>("NodeIndex") equals o.Field<int>("NodeIndex")
                  select new
                  {
                      ID = o.Table.Columns["ID"],
                      FirstName = o.Table.Columns["FirstName"],
                      SurName = o.Table.Columns["SurName"],
                      NodeName = n.Table.Columns["NodeName"],
                      TranslatorName = o.Table.Columns["TranslatorName"],
                      EMail = o.Table.Columns["EMail"],
                      LastLogin = o.Table.Columns["LastLogin"]

                  }).ToList();

    rptList.DataSource = result;
    rptList.DataBind();
```

ASPX:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" OnItemCommand="rptList_OnItemCommand" ID="rptList">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table class="tblRegister">
            <tr class="tblRowHeader" style="background-color: rgb(200,200,200)">
                <th>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" Text="TRNSLTFirstname" />
                </th>
                <th>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" Text="TRNSLTSurname" />
                </th>
                <th>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" Text="TRNSLTNode index" />
                </th>
                <th>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" Text="TRNSLTNumber translation" />
                </th>
                <th>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" Text="TRNSLTEmail" />
                </th>
                <th colspan="3">
                    <asp:Label runat="server" Text="TRNSLTLast login" />
                </th>
            </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# OperatorId.HasValue && OperatorId == Convert.ToInt32(Eval("ID"))? "<tr >" : "<tr>" %>
            <td>
                <%# Eval("FirstName") %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%# Eval("SurName") %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%# Eval("NodeIndex") %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%# Eval("TranslatorName") %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%# Eval("EMail") %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%# Eval("LastLogin") %>
                <asp:Image ClientIDMode="Static" ImageUrl="Images/Icons/Add-22x22.png" ID="AddContact" runat="server" Style="visibility: hidden;" />
            </td>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

> Exception: "Additional information: DataBinding: '<>f__AnonymousType0`2[[System.Data.DataTableCollection, System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Data.DataSet, System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' does not contain a property with the name 'FirstName'."

Please if you are going to help me create a post, comment does not usually help me.

Comment: You have to join  them (i guss on the userId) and select the fields you wish to use. then use that as your data source

Comment: Can I use the DataSet.Merge method?

Comment: I'm not sure about `Merge`, but you can quite easily achieve it with Linq

Comment: create an INNER JOIN, or the linq equivalent, between the two tables so you get one result set instead of two. It's just basic SQL querying technique.

Comment: So. The updated answer did work, but now I get an exception in my ASPX page: DataBinding: '<>f__AnonymousType0`2[[System.Data.DataRow, System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Data.DataRow, System.Data,

Comment: Hello, is anyone there?

Comment: @Malphai I checked back here by chance, but if you want to alert people type @ and then their username, otherwise they don't get notified that you added a comment. Also please place the full exception details into your question, rather than in the comments.

Comment: @ADyson Right. Check my updated answer please!

Comment: `does not contain a property with the name 'FirstName'.` tells you everything you need to know. The objects in `result` don't have a property called FirstName, because you aren't selecting it into your custom object. Why have you still got 2 calls to the DB? You can reduce the first two lines of code to one statement and thus remove the need for the third line. Looks like your data layer needs an extra method, maybe.

Comment: @ADyson Check the updated code, I now created the property. But it now reads the string literally, and not the data from the database.

Comment: that's because you're adding the Column object, not the actual data itself.  I'm not sure (because this is just a weird way to do things) but try `o.Field<string>("FirstName")` instead (assuming FirstName is from the Operators table).

Comment: Where should I put `o.Field<string>("FirstName")`?

Comment: It works now, thank you.